# using database for session storage in laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel framework of PHP for development.Now for my application,
    i want to store users sessions in database and in laravel's documentation ,they
    guided how to use database for storing.

but while searching for sessions in database ,i found this [Link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/27/php-sessions-files-vs-database-based/)
    which says that we need to get lock as long as on script is in execution as other 
    scripts can change session's data,so my questions is :-

1. Is laravel handle at its own (internally) ,what that link is saying to do for  using database for sessions?
2. Is laravel provide any functions to do so ,if they do not provide support for this internally or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

LaravelPHP uses the [PdoSessionHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php) by Symfony. As you can see in the source code there is no table locking.

Don't worry about the locking and use the Laravel database driver for sessions. Sessions can only change during PHP execution time.